# Easiest way to display location?

Tags: ip-geolocation

What is the most up to date, accurate, turn-key code to inject into a page to automatically read a user's IP and spit out their city... on this page we are borrowing from goingtorain.com I want it to display ... within 3 miles of (dynamic city)

http://www.drillavailable.neighborrow.com/

Comment: would prefer to use a third party widget or something that has their own db and just does everything in one clean input/output.. but yes we have a db if thats the only way to store the ip then read it and output the location

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another one we've been looking at to use is http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity. Looks to be fairly simple to setup and is open source/free with apis for most popular languages.

Not done much other than play with it for 5 mins but looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with **location aware browsing**. Look into the [W3C GeoLocation API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API#Deployment_in_web_browsers).

For example, try [Google Gears Geolocation module](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html).

These technologies allow your clients to be geolocalized not only by looking and their IP (which can have 200km offsets) but also by triangulating SSID information from nearby wireless Access Points, and this can be extremely precise.

Once you have the (lon,lat) coordinates, it's just a matter of calling some webservice to get the nearest city's name.

Comment: beware this, most most browsers do not open as default (or do not have it at all)

Comment: Quite the reverse! Most browsers **do**. I just tested all the browsers I have installed on this machine and they all support location aware browsing by default: FireFox, PaleMoon, Opera, Google Chrome and SRWare Iron. 5 out of 5. And I'm sure other Gecko-based and WebKit-based browsers support it as well, on different platforms.

Comment: what I mean is: the browser will ask user to choose (if they wanna share the location).. which what I mean not open as default

Comment: Check http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/ , they not open by default. btw, why let other people gather your user's data, while you have a perfect chance to do so? http://simfool.com vip tracking

Comment: Indeed, as with most things that will affect users' privacy, a confirmation popup will appear to ask if they're willing to disclose their location to that page. With plain IP-based geolocation, results can be **very** inaccurate: in my case (via _simfool_ or whatever other IP-based solution) the position detected is 240km away, therefore not acceptable for OP's question (asking for 3 miles precision).

Comment: Quote: "Then Firefox sends this information to the default geolocation service provider, Google Location Services, to get an estimate of your location." Theres no magic way to get location, just a simple fact is: Google Location Service is better than others

Answer (score 1):

I would choose the locator API at http://ipinfodb.com You can access it via XML or JSON, send it your API key and an IP and it will return the city, state, zip, country, etc. You can then parse the results in your language of choice. Its the simplest way to achieve this without actually storing any information about IP/location routing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need to use the ClientLocation object in the google.loader namespace. In total the whole code is.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" language="javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
if (google.loader.ClientLocation != null) {
  alert(google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city);
} else {
  alert("Not found");
}
</script>
```

The properties available are

- google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude
- google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude
- google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city
- google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country
- google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code
- google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region